# Find the limits of integration on the region D of the triple integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

The problem say the following

Let the triple integral $\iiint _{D}f(x,y,z)dxdydz$ where $D$ is the
region bounded by surfaces $a(x^2+y^2)=xz(a-z)$, $xz=ay$,$yz=ax$ and that contains the point $M=(a/8,a/12,a/2)$.Represent the integral in a iterated integral$\int_{p}^{q} \iint_{D}f(x,y,z)dxdy$
.
Simply I can't draw the region bounded by the surfaces,and therefore get the limits of integration of the region, any recommendation is accepted.
Im try use the intersection with the axis and the planes $XY$, $XZ$, $YZ$ but I obtain ecuations complicated except by the linear expression, but the other I'm simply can't reduce to a simple form in the space, I'm try quit the terms $xz$ of the expression apply an change of coordinates, but I'm fail.
Relly any help and recommendation help me much to do this interesting calculus problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sean $x_0,y_0,z_0$ las coordenadas del punto $M_{0}$ respectivamente para $x,y,z$, notemos que $x_{0},y_{0},z_{0}$ cumplen las desigualdades $a(x_{0}^{2}+y_{0}^2)<x_{0}z_{0}(a-z_{0})$,$x_{0}z_{0}<ay_{0}$,$y_{0}z_{0}<ax_{0}$ Como $M_{0}\in D$ implica que cualquier punto $W\in D$ debe cumplir las desigualdades

$a(x^{2}+y^2)<xz(a-z)$ $(1)$

$xz<ay$  $(2)$

$yz<ax$  $(3)$

Como $a\neq 0$ pues $M_{0}$ debe estar bien definido, entonces  $(1)$ es no negativa, luego $0<a(x^2+y^2)<xz(a-z)$implica que $0<xz(a-z)$ de esto inferimos que hay dos posibilidades:\

$0<x$, $0<z<a$

$x<0$,$z<0$ y $a<z$

En el segundo caso tenemos que $z\in(-\infty,0)\cup (a,+\infty)$ mientras $x<0$ es una región no acotada según las desigualdades $xz<ay$,$yz<ax$,$x<0$,$z<0$ y $x<0$,$z>a$,$xz<ay$,$yz<ax$, por tanto sólo nos quedamos con la primera desiigualdad, de la cual podemos inferir que la pryección de $D$ sobre el eje $OZ$ es justamente $(0,a)$, luego consideremos el plano $z=z_{0}$ que intersecte a $D$ por toodo el intervalo $(0,a)$, ahora fijemos $z_{0} \in (0,a)$ de esto sabemos que se genera una región en el plano $z=z_{0}$, esto es
$$D_{z_{0}}=\lbrace (x,y,z)|z=z_{0},a(x^{2}+y^2)=xz_{0}(a-z_{0}),xz_{0}=ay,yz_{0}=ax\rbrace $$
Ahora notemos que la región $D_{Z_{0}}$ al estar en el plano $z=z_{0}$ entonces $z$ es constante, por tanto podemos determinar que tipo de región está acotada por las igualdades de $D_{z_{0}}$, primero pongamos las regiones y luego hallemos la intersección. \

$a(x^{2}+y^2)=xz_{0}(a-z_{0})$ $(i)$

$xz_{0}=ay$ $(ii)$

$yz_{0}=ax$ $(iii)$

Desarrolamos  $(i)$

$$a(x^{2}+y^2)=xz_{0}(a-z_{0})=$$
$$x^2+y^2=\frac{1}{a}x(a-z_{0})$$
$$x^2+y^2=\frac{1}{a}(xca-xz_{0}^2)$$
$$x^2+y^2=xc(1-\frac{z_{0}}{a})$$
$$x^2-xz_{0}(1-\frac{z_{0}}{a})+y^2=0$$
$$(x-xz_{0}(1-\frac{z_{0}}{2}))^2+y^2=(\frac{c}{2}(1-\frac{z_{0}}{a}))^2$$
Por tanto es una circunferencia con centro en $C=(\frac{z_{0}}{2}(1-\frac{z_{0}}{a}),0)$ y radio \
$r=\frac{z_{0}}{2}(1-\frac{z_{0}}{a})$, además $(ii)$ y $(iii)$ podemos ver fácilmente que se trata de las rectas $y=\frac{z_{0}}{a}x$ e $y=\frac{a}{z_{0}}x$, ahora bien la región acotada por las tres regiones simultaneamente está dada por\
\includegraphics[scale=0.9]{C:/Users/brien/Pictures/777}
\
Ahora veamos que en consecuencia al proyectar $D_{z_{0}}$ tenemos $D_{z}$ cuando $D$ $z_{0}=0$ es $D_{z_0}$ Ahora vamos a plantear la integral triple, pues mientras $$y\in [0,\frac{z_{0}}{2}(1-\frac{z_{0}}{a})]$$ entonces $$\frac{z_{0}}{a}y<=x<=\frac{a}{z_{0}}y$$ De esto planteamos la integral
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{z_{0}}{2}(1-\frac{z_{0}}{a})} \int_{\frac{z_{0}}{a}y}^{\frac{a}{z_{0}}y}f(x,y,z)dxdy$$
Ahora como $z$ varía a lo más hasta $a$ tenemos que la integral pedida queda
$$ \int_{p}^{q} dz  \int \int_{D_{z}} f(x,y,z)dxdy=$$
$$\int_{p}^{q}dz \int  \int_{D_{z_0}} f(x,y,z)dxdy=$$
$$\int_{0}^{a}dz \int_{0}^{\frac{z_{0}}{2}(1-\frac{z_{0}}{a})} \int_{\frac{z_{0}}{a}y}^{\frac{a}{z_{0}}y} f(x,y,z)dxdy$$
Que es lo que nos pedían.

Comment: I believe you're only asked to find the upper and lower limit for $z$ and to write the domain $D$ as a set of inequalities on $x, y$. An iterated integral over $x$ and $y$ is complicated because, for a given $z$, $D$ is bounded by the two lines $x z = a y$ and $y z = a x$ and by an arc of the circle $a (x^2 + y^2) = x z (a - z)$.

Comment: It is my solution, but, if you can help me, I appreciate it.

Comment: The problem, say that I need find these $p$ and $q$ and find $D_{Z} $ that is The projection over the plane $XY$ on $D$ but I dont sure about My answer.